# .prj for NAD_1983_Canada_Atlas_Lambert not recognized correctly

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal

I'm a fairly new user of QGIS and I've run into an issue that I can't seem to solve on my own. I'm trying to work with the [NRCan Atlas of Canada Waterbodies SHP file](http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/e9931fc7-034c-52ad-91c5-6c64d4ba0065.html) but I'm having an issues re-projecting other datasets to line up with this one.

When I reviewed the .PRJ file packaged with the NRCan data, it indicates it is Lambert Conformal Conic projection with two standard parallels at 49°N and 77°N (see .PRJ text below); however, when I add the file to QGIS (v1.8.0-Lisboa) and view the layer properties, the CRS is displayed as follows:

> USER:100001 -  * Generated CRS (+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-95 +k_0=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs)

Note that the second standard parallel (which should be in there as '+lat_2=77') is missing... I'm hoping this explains why my other datasets aren't lining up when I project them, but I can't seem to get QGIS to recognize the second parallel.

Suggestions? Or is this second parallel not an issue for re-projecting data?

---

### Unmodified NRCan .PRJ file contents

```
 PROJCS["NAD_1983_Canada_Atlas_Lambert",
 GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
  DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
  SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
  PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
  UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
 PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
  PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
  PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
  PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-95.0],
  PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",49.0],
  PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",77.0],
  PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",49.0],
  UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Comment: I think the CRS of this shapefile might be EPSG:3979. N.

Comment: @nhopton, i think you might be right about the EPSG code. But I'm still wondering if QGIS is correctly interpreting the second standard parallel.

Comment: I was getting a similar issue but only on Linux - Windows QGIS could find the right projection: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2013-November/024805.html I'm not sure how to get the missing projections into QGIS by default (proj4 is missing them maybe?).

Comment: In that mailing list post, is a link to my projected dataset that you can steal the prj file from to see if that works for you too.

Comment: I've updated the [ticket](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5191), I'll take a peek either tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you found is an already known bug, and has some tickets for GDAL:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4605

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5191

To solve the problem, `Set CRS for Layer` to EPSG:3979, then `Save As ...` to another name.

With that, a .qpj file is added with the correct EPSG code, which will QGIS force to use that.

---

**EDIT**

Ogr2ogr seems to read the projection correctly, so running

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 waterwgs.shp AC_1M_Waterbodies.shp
```

converts the shapefiles to a CRS that QGIS can load without misplacement.

Comment: thanks very much for the links; that very much describes the issue. I don't seem to have EPSG:3978 or EPSG:3979 available when I try to `Set Layer CRS`, so I'm unable to force it to be 3978. Though this seems to be an issue with my database of CRS' rather than an issue with the solution.

Comment: @Andre Do you know if those have patches? I don't see them referenced in the bug tickets. I'd like to compile gdal with those patches to test this out. I only get this problem on Linux - Windows with QGIS 2.0.1 can set the projection properly as EPSG:3978 or EPSG:3979

Comment: You get those EPSG codes if you switch to QGIS 2.0.1 or GDAL 1.10.1. kyle has added some patches now, but I have to wait until it gets into the Windows binaries.

Comment: If someone takes a look at the ticket(s) and agrees with my logic, I'll apply it to the trunk and it should get into Tamas' dev build after that.  Thanks for the reporting.

Comment: Checked in to the trunk.  Should be available in dev builds tomorrow.

Comment: Tested with todays gisinternals: gdalsrsinfo reports right now. Strangely ogr2ogr converting the canadian Waterbodies shapefiles to WGS84 works correctly in GDAL 1.10 and latest dev.