# Help converting a WKT projection to proj4

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I have shapefile (from the local government gis office of a town in Massachusetts) that contains, in the corresponding `.shp.xml` file, the following WKT projection:

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",200000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",750000.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-71.5],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",41.71666666666667],
    PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",42.68333333333333],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",41.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Loading the shapefile into QGIS results in a null CRS ("This layer appears to have no projection specification...").  I've tried converting the above projection into proj4 syntax, but I'm running into some problems caused by the fact that I have no idea what I am doing.

The above projection is awfully close to the [standard projection used by MassGIS](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26986/prettywkt/) (`epsg:26986`), although "Standard_Parallel_1" and "Standard_Parallel_2" are swapped. Trying to convert this to `proj4` syntax using the Python `osgeo.osr` module results in:

```
ERROR 6: No translation for Lambert_Conformal_Conic to PROJ.4 format is known.
```

I can replace `Lambert_Conformal_Conic` with `Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP` (as suggested elsewhere), which results in a successful export in `proj4` syntax, but (a) it's not clear to me that's the right thing to do, and in any case (b) the resulting projection still doesn't place the features where they belong.

How do I get this data in the right place?

**Edit**: I have tried just using `epsg:29686` as well, which didn't work either. The shapefile in question is [here](http://chunk.io/larsks/b1caf06ca29f4c819626028854a8ecbe).

Comment: If the data's not lining up with 26986, that might not be the correct coordinate system. Can you post a sample coordinate pair plus approximately where it is (city, county)?

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128266/qgis-error-6-no-translation-for-lambert-conformal-conic-to-proj-4-format-is-kn and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81633/qgis-not-interpreting-lambert-conformal-conic-projection-correctly

Comment: @Andrej That first answer is part of the "suggested elsewhere" in my question :). I hadn't seen the second one.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shapefile you linked has this `.prj` file content:

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Massachusetts_Mainland_FIPS_2001_Feet",
 GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",
  SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
  PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
  UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
 PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],
  PARAMETER["False_Easting",656166.6666666665],
  PARAMETER["False_Northing",2460625.0],
  PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-71.5],
  PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",41.71666666666667],
  PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",42.68333333333333],
  PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",41.0],
  UNIT["Foot_US",0.3048006096012192]]
```

which is equivalent to `EPSG:2249 NAD83 / Massachusetts Mainland (ftUS)` but has units in feet instead of the meter-based CRS in the `.shp.xml` file (that QGIS ignores).

If you drag and drop the file into QGIS, it builds this custom CRS:

```
 +proj=lcc +lat_1=41.71666666666667 +lat_2=42.68333333333333 +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-71.5 +x_0=199999.9999999999 +y_0=750000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs
```

which gets misplaced in northern Africa, whereas the built-in EPSG CRS has

```
 +proj=lcc +lat_1=42.68333333333333 +lat_2=41.71666666666667 +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-71.5 +x_0=200000.0001016002 +y_0=750000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs
```

Assigning the EPSG code 2249 to the layer with `Set Layer CRS` places it to the right spot compared to an Openstreetmap background:

[image]

This should work the same way for the meter-based CRS.

Comment: That was it, thanks! For what it's worth, when I import the file into qgis (Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer) it shows up as having no CRS, rather than building the custom one you show in this answer. I wonder why you are seeing different behavior? I'm running qgis 2.18.14.

Comment: Yes, QGIS seems to behave a bit strange with CRS it can not recover. In another try, I got the CRS in meters instead of feet.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the Proj.4 string with gdalsrsinfo.

```
gdalsrsinfo voting_precincts.prj -o proj4
+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.71666666666667 +lat_2=42.68333333333333 +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-71
.5 +x_0=199999.9999999999 +y_0=750000 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs
```

This variant is a bit different than what we have seen in your question and other answers with +datum=NAD83. However, it should be possible to put data into correct place in QGIS by using just the menus.

1) Open the shapefile, go to Set Layer CRS. You should find an entry for Generated CRS under the User Defined Coordinate Systems.

[image]

There can be many automatically generated CRS definitions, be sure to select the one that was built for the VOTING_PRECINCTS and press OK. With my QGIS 2.18.10 data appear near to Boston.

[image]

The order of lat_1 and lat_2 does not seem to play a role here, nor the missing -datum=NAD83

Comment: When I open this file in QGIS 2.18.14, it shows up as having no CRS and there are no entries under "user defined coordinate systems".  Odd.

Comment: Can you add your own CRS through Settings - Custom CRS with the provided Proj4 string and then use that for voting_precincts?

Comment: Based on @AndreJ's answer, it seems as if `EPSG:2249` is the correct SRID.

Comment: Man, this just saved me after a couple hours of fiddling. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use [EPSG:26986](http://epsg.io/26986) which is listed as

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / Massachusetts Mainland",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",42.68333333333333],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",41.71666666666667],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",41],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-71.5],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",200000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",750000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","26986"]]
```

I don't think the order of the standard parallels matters but you could swap them if you wanted.

Comment: You'll note that I mentioned that very same CRS in my question.  Using it does not correctly place the features. Maybe the shapefile is bad?  I've updated the question with a link to the shapefile in question.

Comment: But you changed it in the question

Comment: Well, no, but perhaps my question is unclear. I've also updated it to indicate that I did try using epsg:29686 without success.

Comment: By reading https://community.esri.com/thread/49519 the order of standard parallels do not matter in ESRI software. It may make a difference for Proj.4. If it does it is perhaps a bug.

Comment: It might be the absence of `_2SP` in the PROJECTION parameter that causes the trouble for PROJ.4.

Comment: EPSG:26986 has horizontal units of Meters and EPSG:2249 has units of feet.  EPSG:2249 was the correct projection in this case.  Looking at the original post's WKT, it looks like that WKT does not match EPSG:2249 but rather matches EPSG:26986.  This would explain why it was showing up in the wrong place.